# Will a ferromagnet retain its magnetic properties after reaching the curie point?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

If a piece of iron or any kind of ferromagnet reaches its Tc, it will lose all it's magnetic properties, and will not be affected by an external magnetic field, if it drops back to room temperature or below Tc will it regain its magnetic properties and get attracted without losing anything or get "damaged" from the heat? 
And will this always happen with all kinds of ferromagnets?

Also, if a feromagnet's Tc is 500C for example, will it operate the same way in the presence of an external magnetic field at 450C just like in room temperature or will there be a weaker effect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid I disagree with @Prabhapar Bhimalapuram: the Curie point is the temperature of the transition from a ferromagnetic to a paramagnetic, so there are no domains above Curie temperature (in the bulk, though there can be surface domains). Domains often have random directions below the Curie point.

Answer (score 1):

The originally magnetic material after  heated and then cooling, will NO longer be a magnet.  That being said, it can be magnetized again by putting it in a strong enough magnetic field.

The thinking is as follows. Magnetic material has tiny (microscopic) domains which can be thought of as a material unit for magnetic orientation. Magnet is that state of material in which the domains align giving rise to a net non-zero magnetization, which is observed as material acting as a magnet. However, once heated above critical point, the orientation of domains become random, and the material looses its magnetization. When cooled, unless it is very slowly, the domains will keep their random orientation and hence even after bring it back to original temperature, the material has zero net magnetization.

However, you can now magnetize the material by applying a strong magnetic field, which will orient the domains. Once material is magentized, even when the external magnetic field is removed, the material will remain magnetized.

Comment: just wanted to add a video which clearly demonstrates this effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUz1ZaIHvDs. This is done in the field of a strong Neodymium magnetic so that the field can be recreated once the sample (Ni here) cools down.

Answer (score 0):

As for second part of question - this depends on material, but as we get closer to Curie point magnetization gets lower. It could be slight change  in case of first order transitions where there is sudden drop of magnetization. But for more common second order transitions magnetization change is continuous so it will get weak near transition. 
As for the first part if you cool without magnetic field your magnet will lose it's magnetization. But even if it's not magnetized it will be attracted by other magnets. And it can be magnetized again. If there is no chemical change (like oxidation for example) on passing Curie point it's totally reversible. It's like that for every ferromagnet.

As a side-note ferromagnet in its paramagnetic state (above Curie temperature) *will* be affected by field - there would be no permanent magnetization of course, but it will certainly magnetize in applied field.